Jetpack Compose TopBar is pushed up on keyboard show
I have a KMM project with shared UI.
I have a chat screen where there's a top bar with chat info, list of messages and Input field to write new messages.
My problem is that when keyboard appears all the content is pushed up including TopAppBar.
And I want that only LazyColumn is resized and the TopBar is pinned.
Of course I have android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" in my manifest for AndroidApp
The code is below
Scaffold(
    modifier = Modifier
        .statusBarsPadding()
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .background(Color.White)
        .nestedScroll(scrollBehavior.nestedScrollConnection),
    topBar = {
        TopAppBar(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .requiredHeight(56.dp)
                .background(Color.White),
            title = {
                Row(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .requiredHeight(56.dp),
                    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
                ) {
                    Image(
                        modifier = Modifier.height(44.dp).width(44.dp).clickable(enabled = true) {
                            component.onEvent(ChatRoomEvents.BackClick)
                        },
                        contentScale = ContentScale.None,
                        painter = painterResource(Res.drawable.back_green),
                        contentDescription = Strings.getString("back")
                    )
                    SeafarerImage(
                        modifier = chatRoomImageModifier,
                        picture = component.chatRoom.pic,
                        placeHolder = if (component.chatRoom.isSupport) Res.drawable.nextship_logo_short else Res.drawable.empty_seafarer_chat
                    )
                    Column(
                        modifier = Modifier.weight(1f).height(41.dp).padding(start = 8.dp)
                    ) {
                        Text(
                            modifier = Modifier.height(19.dp),
                            text = component.chatRoom.userName ?: "",
                            textAlign = TextAlign.Start,
                            style = getTypography().subtitle1,
                            maxLines = 1,
                            overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis
                        )
                        Text(
                            modifier = Modifier.height(19.dp),
                            text = "last seen recently", // TODO time
                            textAlign = TextAlign.Start,
                            style = getTypography().subtitle2,
                            fontSize = 13.sp,
                            color = lightGreen,
                            maxLines = 1,
                            overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis
                        )
                    }
                    Image(
                        modifier = Modifier.height(44.dp).width(44.dp).clickable(enabled = true) {
                            component.onEvent(ChatRoomEvents.SendMessage)
                        },
                        contentScale = ContentScale.None,
                        painter = painterResource(Res.drawable.trash),
                        contentDescription = Strings.getString("delete_chat")
                    )
                    Spacer(Modifier.width(6.dp))
                }
            }
        )
    },
    content = { innerPadding ->
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(innerPadding)
        ) {
            LazyColumn(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .weight(1f)
                    .background(brush),
                state = listState,
                reverseLayout = true
            ) {
                item {
                    if (screenState.isLoading) ProgressIndicator()
                }
                items(
                    count = messages.size
                ) { index ->
                    ChatItem(messages[index], component.dateFormat)
                }
            }

            if (!listState.isScrollInProgress) {
                if (!listState.canScrollForward && listState.canScrollBackward && component.needNextPage)
                    component.getNextPage()
            }

            CommentRow(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                interactionSource = commentInteractionSource,
                currentText = screenState.messageText ?: "",
                sendEnabled = true,//!screenState.isLoading && screenState.currentText?.isNotEmpty() == true,
                onTextChange = { newText -> component.onEvent(ChatRoomEvents.MessageTextChanged(newText)) },
                onSendClick = { component.onEvent(ChatRoomEvents.SendMessage) }
            )
        }
    }
)

comments row:
@OptIn(ExperimentalResourceApi::class)
@Composable
fun CommentRow(
    modifier: Modifier,
    interactionSource: MutableInteractionSource,
    currentText: String,
    sendEnabled: Boolean,
    onTextChange: (String) -> Unit,
    onSendClick: () -> Unit,
) {
    Row(
        modifier = modifier
            .wrapContentHeight()
            .navigationBarsPadding()
            .background(Color.White)
    ) {
        BasicTextField(
            modifier = Modifier
                .weight(1f)
                .heightIn(50.dp, 100.dp)
                .background(Color.White)
                .padding(start = 20.dp, top = 10.dp, bottom = 10.dp),
            interactionSource = interactionSource,
            textStyle = getTypography().subtitle2,
            value = currentText,
            onValueChange = { newText -> onTextChange(newText) },
            maxLines = 3,
        )
        Spacer(Modifier.width(10.dp))
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .width(48.dp)
        ) {
            Image(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .height(26.dp)
                    .width(26.dp)
                    .offset(y = 13.dp)
                    .clickable(enabled = sendEnabled) { onSendClick() },
                painter = painterResource(if (sendEnabled) Res.drawable.send_message else Res.drawable.send_message_disabled),
                contentDescription = Strings.getString("send_message")
            )
        }
    }
}

Also my main activity looks this way:
I use Decompose library for navigation
MaterialTheme {
    val childStack by root.childStack.subscribeAsState()

    Scaffold(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().background(mainTextColor),
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxHeight()
                .background(mainTextColor),
        ) {
            var showBottomBar = false
            Children(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().weight(1F),
                stack = childStack
            ) { child ->
                when (val instance = child.instance) {
                    is RootComponent.Child.NoInternetChild -> {
                        InternetErrorScreen(instance.component)
                    }
                    is RootComponent.Child.SplashChild -> SplashScreen()
                    is RootComponent.Child.AuthChild -> AuthStart(instance.component)
                    is RootComponent.Child.PasswordRecoveryChild -> RecoverPassword(instance.component)
                    is RootComponent.Child.NewPasswordChild -> NewPassword(instance.component)
                    is RootComponent.Child.SearchChild -> {
                        showBottomBar = true
                        SearchScreen(instance.component)
                    }
                    is RootComponent.Child.SeafarerProfileChild -> SeafarerDataScreen(instance.component)
                    is RootComponent.Child.GeneralDataChild -> GeneralDataScreen(instance.component)
                    is RootComponent.Child.ContactsChild -> SeafarerContactsScreen(instance.component)
                    is RootComponent.Child.WorkExperienceChild -> WorkExperienceScreen(instance.component)
                    is RootComponent.Child.DocsChild -> DocsScreen(instance.component)
                    is RootComponent.Child.ChatChild -> {
                        showBottomBar = true
                        ChatRoomsScreen(instance.component)
                    }
                    is RootComponent.Child.MainChild -> {
                        showBottomBar = true
                        MainScreen(instance.component)
                    }
                    is RootComponent.Child.StatsChild -> TODO()
                    is RootComponent.Child.SeafarerDocumentsChild -> DocumentsScreen(instance.component)
                    is RootComponent.Child.BiometricsChild -> BiometricsScreen(instance.component)
                    is RootComponent.Child.VideoResumeChild -> VideoResumeScreen(instance.component)
                    is RootComponent.Child.ReviewsChild -> ReviewsScreen(instance.component)
                    is RootComponent.Child.ColleaguesChild -> ColleaguesScreen(instance.component)
                    is RootComponent.Child.CommentsChild -> CommentsScreen(instance.component)
                    is RootComponent.Child.VacancyChild -> VacancyInfoScreen(instance.component)
                    is RootComponent.Child.SettingsChild -> SettingsScreen(instance.component)
                    is RootComponent.Child.ChatRoomChild -> ChatRoomScreen(instance.component)
                }
            }
            if (showBottomBar) {
                BottomBar(
                    root,
                    Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .navigationBarsPadding()
                )
            }
        }
    }
}




No keyboard
Keyboard









I want the top bar is fixed on the screen

Welcome to stackoveflow! If you found an answer useful, you can mark it as accepted answer by clicking the checkmark at the left side of the answer.

You should use a Scaffold Composable. It provides dedicated slots for things like a TopAppBar. You can use it like this:
Scaffold(
    topBar = {
        TopAppBar(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .requiredHeight(56.dp),
            backgroundColor = Color.White,
            contentColor = Color.Black, // Change content color as needed
            title = {
                //...
            }
        )
    },
    content = { innerPadding ->
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(innerPadding)
        ) {
            LazyColumn(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .weight(1f)
                    .background(brush),
                state = listState,
                reverseLayout = true
            ) {
                item {
                    if (screenState.isLoading) ProgressIndicator()
                }
                items(
                    count = messages.size
                ) { index ->
                    ChatItem(messages[index], component.dateFormat)
                }
            }

            if (!listState.isScrollInProgress) {
                if (!listState.canScrollForward && listState.canScrollBackward && component.needNextPage)
                    component.getNextPage()
            }

            CommentRow(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().imePadding(),
                interactionSource = commentInteractionSource,
                currentText = screenState.messageText ?: "",
                sendEnabled = true,//!screenState.isLoading && screenState.currentText?.isNotEmpty() == true,
                onTextChange = { newText -> component.onEvent(ChatRoomEvents.MessageTextChanged(newText)) },
                onSendClick = { component.onEvent(ChatRoomEvents.SendMessage) }
            )

        }
    }
)

The Scaffold will ensure that the TopAppBar stays visible, even when the content is pushed up because of the keyboard. Also, I added the imePadding Modifier to shift the content upwards when the keyboard opens.
Also, have a look at the official sample app called JetChat. It implements a chat interface following best practices. Especially check out the Conversation.kt file.

No it didn't help. The top bar still goes up and it's not visible.
I tried to put my code here, but I don't know how to do it in comments.

You can edit your question and provide updated code there.

Make sure that the Scaffold I have in my answer is not contained in a Column or similar. It should be the top level Compoable of a destination in your Navhost.

Oh thanks. I edited the main question. It seems to be that my scaffold is really inside the column. Of main app window. But I don't know how to get rid of it

It is good that you added the info that you are using Decomposer for navigation. I am not familiar with it, maybe someone else can hop in to help.

The problem was solved by adding
.imePadding()

to the modifier of the main scaffold of main activity.
Found it here
